# How do i mock REST back end in an android app

Tags: android

My android app communicate with back end service through REST API . I want to mock out this API to quickly develop the front end. I am using android volley as client side networking library..

Comment: What do you mean with this : `I want to mock out this API to quickly develop the front end`

Comment: use firebase? or some other json hosting service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would store mock data as json in my assets folder and create my data from these json files:

```
fun getJsonFromAssets(context: Context, jsonPath: String): String? {
    return try {
        context.assets.open(jsonPath).bufferedReader().use{
            it.readText()
        }
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        null
    }
}
```

and then get the object like (here for example for a list):

```
val list = gson.fromJson<List<MyObject>>(jsonString, object : TypeToken<List<MyObject>>() {}.type)
```

Comment: Can you show your code ?